# Connection refused on minikube service

Tags: kubernetes-helm, minikube

I have phpfpm, mariadb and apache pods on minikube. All pods, containers, services also other related components working now and I can able to access with 'curl localhost' to access main page in apache container. Even though I use NodePort and expose the web server service, when I try to 'curl IP', I encountered "Connection refused" error.

Debian 9.9 on GCP.
minikube version: v1.1.0
helm version: v2.14.0

```
replicaCount: 1
image:
  name: 7.3-apache
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
nginxService:
  name: nginx
  type: NodePort
  externalPort: 80
  internalPort: 8080
phpfpmService:
  name: phpfpm
  type: NodePort
  phpfpmPort: 9000
ingress:
  enabled: false
config:
  nginx.conf: |-
    server {
      listen 0.0.0.0:8080;
      root /app;
      location / {
        index index.html index.php;
      }
      location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass phpfpm-php-app-phpfpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
      }
    }
```

I expect to connect web server with: http://192.168.99.102:30335 but I can't.

Comment: Showing only the variables file you used to install the chart is insufficient details. Show the deployed service description as well. Also, how did you get the IP you mentioned?

Comment: Yeah, please add the following commands output: `kubectl get svc` and `minikube ip`.